# Make an MDI child form no longer a child

Tags: vb.net, mdichild

Using VB.Net:

Is there a way to make a child form that is inside an MDI parent form no longer a child form?  For example, I have an entryForm.vb inside of mainForm.vb.  On double click (or other event) I want entryForm.vb to be fully sizable and outside of the mainForm.vb without losing text.

I have tried changing the MDI settings of entryForm.vb but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried setting `MDIParent` of the form to `Nothing`?

Comment: wow! that did it! I tried setting it "me" and everything except nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `MDIParent` of the form instance to `Nothing`